# How can I sync photos to a network drive over wifi?

Tags: wi-fi, sync, motorola-droid, file-management

My current workflow is to snap pics on my Droid, plug it in via USB, and sync the pics. I'd like to just run a script to sync the DCIM folder with a shared network drive, if anyone knows of a way that I can do this?

I can connect to the share with a file explorer app, but copying the files is even more awkward that way than plugging in the USB. The tech is there, I'm just wondering if there's a simple one-touch solution.

Comment: I asked this [question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2172/15) regarding the easiest way to push pictures to a photo site. You may want to use your network drive in the end but if not, I recommend [PicPush](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=picpush). Once you set it up, snap a picture and it's uploaded automatically. It's zero-touch. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Image Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/image-transfer/com.t3ch.imagetransfer).

Comment: Looks good. Reviews mention a free version, but I can't see that anywhere. Anyone know if there is a free/lite version to try it out? Otherwise I guess I'll take the plunge and rely on the Market's 24hr money back.

Answer (score 2):

[Upload 2 NAS](http://www.appbrain.com/app/upload-2-nas/com.rcreations.upload2nas) can do this, and there is also a lite version. I haven't actually *used* this but it's on my list to try.

Comment: I can see uses for scheduled batch upload, interesting find.

Comment: Had a play with Upload 2 NAS, but it only seems to be able to upload to FTP servers, not shared folders.

Answer (score 1):

I would always go for rsync

if your phone is not rooted you could use
rsync4android (which is free)
https://market.android.com/details?id=eu.kowalczuk.rsync4android

if your phone is rooted you could offcourse also use the above but if you need more advance stuff I would combine BTEP (Better Terminal Emulator Pro, not free) which has a cli ssh client which can be called from SL4A (scripting engine usefull for BASH scripts, which is free)