# Android and Network attached storage server

Tags: wi-fi, networking, storage

I am trying to organize my digital archive (pictures and movies).  My wife and I store a lot of stuff  on our Android phones. Before I buy a NAS device I would love to hear which protocol I should be looking to use with a NAS. What I want is to connect my Andoid phone in most natural way to a NAS and to be able read, write and use pictures from the NAS.

Is there any good client for NAS servers, or is there any file explorer which cloud be integrate whit NAS so I can browse files.

It would be ideal if I could find some sync software that would automatically backup data from my phone to a NAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a NAS that uses standard Windows shares (SMB) and I use the [Image Transfer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/image-transfer/com.t3ch.imagetransfer) app to push all my new pictures and videos to my server over wireless (it's a paid app but very cheap and in my opinion worth the small fee).

Also see this previous question: [App to sync photos to a network drive over wifi?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3053/app-to-sync-photos-to-a-network-drive-over-wifi) which has a few alternatives and where Image Transfer came top.

My device comes with a web-page interface, which is how I do most viewing of pictures, files etc

Comment: Image Transfer, that's pretty cool.  I really wish someone would develop a Windows Home Server solution for Android (backup or access data to the server).

Comment: @Bryan I keep idly thinking about it (I have a Windows Home Server) but there's another WHS add-in I want to do first (mobile sync related but not to do with files) and I never find time for that. I know there's an iPhone app for WHS that does some of this backup and restore, so it should be possible to borrow that app's server end, and attach a new Android client to its APIs.

Comment: @Bryan in case you haven't seen it already: WHS Phone https://market.android.com/details?id=com.whsphonetrial

Comment: Nice!  Thanks for sharing, I'll check that out for sure.  I absolutely love my WHS :)

Answer (score 2):

[ES File explorer](http://www.estrongs.com/en/products/file-explorer.html) has the ability to connect to any shared folder using SMB, I’ll recommend you to give a try.

If what you want is the possibility to copy files manually from/to your NAS server from/to the phone, this is a perfect solution, it’s free, easy to configure and super easy to use.

If what you want is an automatic sync of some phone folders to your NAS shared sources, then you are searching for something else.

Answer (score 0):

As technology and apps have moved on....I've tried a few different apps,the best IMHO being ES and FS file explorers from Google Play to manage/stream  pictures,video and music and files, but I've found X-plore to be the easiest to get on with juggling files. Microsoft WHS2003 and a 2015 Android smartphone in synergy - who would have thought it?