# Is there a way to automatically sync photos taken on my phone to picasa web albums?

Tags: picasa, photos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the most effortless way for “cloud” back up of photos taken with an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2172/whats-the-most-effortless-way-for-cloud-back-up-of-photos-taken-with-an-androi)

Is there a way to automatically sync photos taken on my phone to picasa web albums?

In the Gallery I can see albums from the web synced to my phone but not the other way round.

Comment: Seems like a repeat to [this question](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2172/15). Anyway, [PicPush](http://www.appbrain.com/search?q=picpush) was suggested as an answer. It works as expected, pushing pictures to Picasa from one of my phone's folders. It does so automatically once you set it up. Set and forget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.androlib.com/android.application.com-pixelpipe-android-com-picasa-qmFq.aspx) app does it using a pixelpipe account (auto-upload, not sync). There are some which do this through dropbox. For some reason, this is still not directly possible using picasa.