# Application to take and share pictures automatically

Tags: photos, automation

Are there any applications that can take a picture and upload to several different services automatically, like Facebook, Twitter (using a third party service), a WordPress blog, etc?

Comment: Similar to [What's the most effortless way for “cloud” back up of photos taken with an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2172/15). PicPush and PixelPipe are two options among many.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**On June 2, 2012, PicPlz announced that they would be closing permanently as of July 3, 2012**

---

[PicPlz](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.picplz.rangefinder).

Not only does it give you a number of effects you can apply to your images (like Hipstamatic) but also automatically posts to  Facebook, Twitter, Flickr, Tumblr, Posterous, Foursquare, and can backup to a Dropbox folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can post photos to twitter (using a third party service) and facebook with [tweetdeck](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.thedeck.android.app).

> TweetDeck is your social browser for Twitter, Facebook, Foursquare and Buzz.
>
> TweetDeck is your mobile browser for staying in touch with what's happening on Twitter,  Facebook, Foursquare and Buzz. TweetDeck makes it easy to stay up to date and organized no matter where you are.
>
> (A Twitter, Facebook, Foursquare or Buzz account is required)